# numpy/pandas - why the selected the element from list are the same by random.choice

Tags: pandas, numpy

there is a list which contains integer values.
list=[1,2,3,.....]
then I use np.random.choice function to select a random element and add it to the a existing dataframe column, please refer to below code

```
df.message = df.message.astype(str) + "rowNumber=" + '"' + str(np.random.choice(list))  + '"'
```

But the element selected by np.random.choice and appended to the message column are always the same for all message row.

What is issue here?

Expected result is that the selected element from the list is not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass to `np.random.choice` with parameter `size` and convert values to strings:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'message' : ['aa','bb','cc']})

L = [1,2,3,4,5]
df.message = (df.message.astype(str) + "rowNumber=" + '"' + 
                np.random.choice(L, size=len(df)).astype(str)  + '"')
print (df)
           message
0  aarowNumber="4"
1  bbrowNumber="2"
2  ccrowNumber="5"
```

Comment: this doesn't get the expected result. the result returned is that whole list([1,2,3....]) is selected and appended after message.

Comment: wait. it works.

Comment: why need map to string then list?